# What does =~ mean?

Tags: shell-script, command-line

Ran across a shell script that had '=~' in a contitional and I was wondering what it meant. Not much luck on Google or SO sites.

Example:

```
if [[ $VAR =~ 'this string' ]]
```

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin That would have worked. If only I had worded my question a little differently it would have probably showed up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a regular expression match operator.

From the `bash` man page:

```
An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same
precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the
right of the operator is considered an extended regular
expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).  The return
value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.
```

See `bash`'s man page for more details (search for `=~`)